# N2CMS MVC - new page under Trash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2cms

I am using N2 CMS (taken templates Dinamico MVC project). I created a new model "TextPage" and respective controller as well. I registered page with "TextPageRegistration" class. And I set parent type for this type as Start Page. But when I run the site, I see this page under Trash instead of under Start Page.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Those things only controls what types of pages can be created under what kind of pages (i.e. you can create a page of type "TextPage" as a child to pages of type "Start Page" in the structure.

If something is in the trashcan, it's there because you (or someone else) deleted the page.
Try moving it back, or create a new page?